# значение слова ВЕТ

Tags: значение-слов

И всё же какое значение и смысл несёт первородное слово ВЕТ, от которого и происходят слова: соВЕТ, отВЕТ, приВЕТ, заВЕТ и так далее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слова "вет" нет ни в одном современном языке, видимо, его и не было. А значение **морфа** "вет" (*вѣт* - откуда *вѣтъ*) исчерпывающе описано у Фасмера.

> вет
>
> только др.-русск. вѣтъ "совет, договор" (Срезн. I, 498), ст.-слав.
>   вѣтъ βουλή (Супр.). Сюда же отве́т, приве́т, обе́т, сове́т, ве́че,
>   отве́тить, отвеча́ть, завеща́ть и т. д.; др. ступень корневого
>   вокализма в вити́я.
>
> Родственно лит. vaitenù "сужу, обсуждаю, полагаю", др.-прусск.
>   waitiāmai "мы говорим", waitiāt "говорить", авест. vaēϑ- "установить
>   судебным следствием", vaēϑa ж. "судебное заключение" (см.
>   Розвадовский, RO 1, 104; Бартоломэ, Air. Wb. 1322; Буга, РФВ 75, 153;
>   Траутман, BSW 339; Apr. Sprd. 455 и сл.). Маретич (AfslPh 10, 134 и
>   сл.) относит сюда же польск. witać, в.-луж. witać, н.-луж. witaś
>   "приветствовать". Менее вероятно предположение Вайана (RES 23, 154) о
>   про- исхождении из *vě- (см. ве́ять), от которого якобы образовано
>   *věto "веялка" (ср. си́то от се́ять), а отсюда *větiti "веять", фигурально "дискутировать, спорить", причем в качестве семантической
>   параллели указывается на лат. ventilāre.